# Emotion recognition matrix input to SVM

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm, stasm

I am going to build an emotion recognition system (based on Paul Ekman's emotion model = happiness, sadness, anger, fear, surprise, disgust, neutral) using STASM and OpenCV's SVM with video clips as the source.

However, I have no clue about what kind of data that should be fed for the training phase itself. I know that we have to input a `Mat` type to the SVM, but I'm wondering what should be included in the matrix.

For example, suppose we have landmark points that we get from STASM. Each landmark point has its own `[x,y]` coordinate. Furthermore, each face expression has many landmarks points, let's say we cover 17 landmark points. That means after knowing those 17 landmark points for one face expression, we will wrap this data to the first row of the matrix data type and feed it into the SVM and then the process is the same for other expressions (we should label them too but let's not focus on that part first).

My question:

1. **Is feeding the x and y coordinates of the landmark points for the system enough?**

Intuitively I don't think it is enough. We should get some sort of displacement from a neutral expression to a 'peak' expression described in this paper [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pmichel/publications/Michel-CSTDissertation.pdf). For example, we can get the Euclidean distance of each landmark point from a neutral state to a happy state and feed the **displacements of the coordinates** to the matrix, instead of the coordinates.

But I feel like there is still something missing with this idea.

2. **If every expression is compared to the neutral state, then how can the machine know if someone's face is in a neutral state?**

I am confused because I don't know to what should the neutral expression comparison be based on since other expressions actually use neutral expression as the comparison.

Comment: very interesting topic, but quite broad as an SO question, don't you think?

Comment: @Miki There are some SO threads out there related to what I'm asking but they are not specific enough. Actually I'm being pretty 'specific' considering the progress of this topic in SO. Also, I believe SO peeps are brilliant people :)

Comment: I partially agree with you (that's why I didn't downvoted). But still your questions are quite broad, in the sense that are not programming related questions, but more research like problems. Hope someone here has an answer for you... in the mean time let's see _Lie to me_ :D

Comment: Perhaps there's something missing with the displacement idea, but I believe that's the way to begin.  Build your infrastructure to measure displacements, feed a (relatively) small data set to train the SVM, and see how well that works for you.  The cases that don't discriminate well should then suggest further improvements -- but you'll have a large part of your code basis vetted, and you can concentrate on new stuff.  BTW, I would think that the midpoint of each upper eyelid would be a significant shift point; that doesn't seem to be one of the 17.

Comment: @Prune thanks for the suggestion. I do realize that 17 landmark points might not be sufficient for emotion recognition. I will still need to fine-tune the numbers because there is a performance trade off as the number of landmark goes up.

Comment: I'm quite aware of the creeping penalties; that's why I suggested a minimal addition.  I would expect that "neutral state" should be -- physiologically -- the state of relaxation at the beginning of meditation.  This is something like sleeping, but upright and with the eyes open.  This would be your "class 0".